# Firefox crashes on driver last window close

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, crash, geckodriver

I have a project that sometimes uses multiple FF windows and sometimes multiple FF drivers.
During init, I create a custom FirefoxProfile (or load a default from Selenium without any changes), add it to DesiredCapabilities, add capabilities to FirefoxOptions and start FF with FirefoxOptions.

Test case executes fine, until I need to close the window:

```
driver.getWindowHandles().forEach(name -> driver.switchTo().window(name).close());
```

or

```
driver.quit();
```

After either one of these pass, FF shuts down and "Firefox has crashed" popup appears. No exception is shown in logs.

[image]

If I remove FirefoxProfile, no crash popup appears, but FirefoxProfile is needed to enable Flash support and do more.

Using:

- Selenium 3.4.0
- Firefox 54 (32 bit)
- Geckodriver 0.17 (32 bit)
- Windows 10, 64bit // Windows 7, 64bit

Comment: I'm not using Geckodriver (I'm working with Selenium 2.5) but I saw many questions and bug reports here and in github on closing the browser. In the meantime [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40064643/5168011) might provide a temporary patch.

Comment: @Guy - I can not kill plugincontainer, since i'm using Flash. And if it was a plugin container issue, then it would show, that 'plugin-container.exe has crashed'

Comment: @Hans looks like it's a know Firefox/geckodriver issue with quitting driver  several people have faced and reported on the same issue. Try using FF v47.0.2 which works fine for me as well.

Comment: Why take the time to close all the window handles for the driver if you're just going to call `quit` anyway? I assume this error  still occurs if you just called `driver.quit()` correct?

Comment: @mrfreester - There was meant to be OR between those 2 lines of cod actually, but yes, the error occurs also, if I only use `driver.quit()`.

Comment: @anshulGupta - I can not use older firefox. Not allowed by upper management and security.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The driver is failing to properly terminate the sub processes created by Firefox like flash.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/285

To avoid the dialogue box, you can set the environemnt variable `XRE_NO_WINDOWS_CRASH_DIALOG` to 1.

Comment: This feels more like hiding the issue not fixing it :)

Comment: I agree, but sometimes you have to live with it if you are not willing to fix it yourself. The sub process should exit after that, so there's probably not much to worry about.

Comment: But whouldn't this disable ALL Windows Crash dialogs?

Comment: This environment variable is specific to Firefox. It won't affect other programs.

Comment: Since this is my only option at the moment, I'll accept this.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah the same error happened for me as well.
I've tried all possibilities but nothing did works except downgrading the firefox.

Now I've 46.01 which is working for me without crash issue.

Comment: As stated in my question comments, I can not downgrade FF. Also this is not a fix but a workaround.