# Zombie firefox and geckodriver processes after a scheduled scraper (headless selenium based) runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, ram

I have 10 tasks which are selenium based scrapers which use celery to schedule and run with Redis as a broker.

Selenium uses **geckodriver** to connect and use Firefox (65.0.1, headless mode) to scrape data.

The problem I am facing is that once a celery worker executes a task that spawns FireFox processes to scrape and even though I use `driver.quit()` at the end of every task, **there are Firefox and geckodriver processes that continue to persist.**

The above is the crux of my issue. It ends up eating most of my RAM and eventually leads to **not enough memory** being available for **other scraper tasks to run.**

Irrespective of the amount of RAM. The selenium task shouldn't be leaving zombie processes even though `driver.quit()` is called.

Any suggestions to resolve this would be great.

Comment: What is your version of FireFox are you using?

Comment: I am using 65.0.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45057141/9105725, recommends killing the process. Seems extreme, but if you have the latest Selenium and Firefox versions, the non-extreme method doesn't seem to be working for you.

Comment: Since these are multiple scrapers running concurrently. A killall firefox after a scraper runs would basically kill another ongoing scraper. Is there a way to direct and kill the specific spawned firefox for that scraper's driver?